# I got this error "Error running command (re-run needed): RPC response error -32002:..."

Tags: alchemy, solana-cli, sugar.js

Solana NFT Uploading Error

[image: 1]

I tried changing the solana creator wallet address and SOL treasury address but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[Error resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkfOU.png)

What I did to resolve the error? I deposited sol token from sol faucet https://solfaucet.com/ under devnet network and then performed the "sugar upload" command at the command prompt. The error was gone and the 28 nft assets were successfully uploaded and ready for deployment. =)